# Springboot restinvokation with an non existing field

Tags: spring-boot

Suppose I have a model `UserInfo` which I used in my post service as `@RequestBody` and when I invoke the service with `UserInfo` payload it is working.

```
Class UserInfo {
    Private String firstName;
    Private String lastName
}
```

How do I restrict the post call if someone sends some additional fields in the payload which is not exists in `UserInfo` model (e.g. `age`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a property to `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

Or create a component:

```java
@Component
public class Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerImpl implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, are you using this?

```
@Autowired
ServiceInterface serviceInterface;

@PostMapping(value = "/userSave")   
@RequestBody    
    public RequestEntity saveUserInfo(**@ModelAttribute** UserInfo userInfo){
return new ResponseEntity(serviceInterface.saveUser(userInfo),HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

when we are using @ModelAttribute annotation this gets only attribute values in UeserInfo DTO (DATA TRANSFER OBJECT). Also, you can use validations in the UserInfo DTO Class. Like

```
Class UserInfo { 

@NotNull
private String firstName;

@NotNull
private String lastName;

}
```

But However when using `@RequestBody` whatever user sends additional data that save only UserInfo Attribute data.